# testng.xml file- testNG project working/running fine via IDE eclipse but not via cmd prompt

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng.xml

Q. testng.xml TestNG project working/running fine via IDE eclipse but not via cmd prompt
- Using testng.xml - Right-click --> Run via TestNG Suite
It is working fine But, If I am using command prompt on windows 10, then its saying class path not found
Below is the XML file I used -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestNgMavenExampleSuite" verbose="2">
  <test name="TestNgMavenTest">
     <classes>
        <class name="test.testcases.LoginTest"/> 
     </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Also, I tried Project clean, Maven build, update project but no result
The command, I am using in cmd prompt to run XML file are as below -

```
1. Go to a project folder
2. Then: `java -cp [projectpath]\lib\*;[projectpath]\target org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`
```

The error I am getting from command prompt -

```
[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: test.testcases.LoginTest
```

Comment: multiple entries in classpath are seperated by colon(:) not semi-colon

Comment: getting this error after updated to : Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG